# if variable != "string" or variable != "string_2" always evaluates the same. Never goes to else

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

My understanding of the following code is that if user_input does not equal "up" or "down", it should keep looping. But if it does equal "up" or "down", then it changes valid_move to True and stops looping. But no matter what the user input is, it always prints ("Invalid entry") and never gets out of the while loop.

```
valid_move = False

while not valid_move:
    user_input = input("enter up or down")
        if user_input != "up" or user_input != "down"):
            print("invalid entry")

        else:
            valid_move = True
            print(user_input)
```

Why is that?

Comment: `or` -> `and` .

Comment: `if user_input not in ('up', 'down')`…

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is your condition, instead of:

```
if user_input != "up" or user_input != "down")
```

Use:

```
if user_input != "up" and user_input != "down")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "and" instead of "or" in your if statement as said by